# How to select the id with max value that in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are 2 tables.

```
Table 1
id  value
1   3
2   2
3   3
4   1
5   4
6   3
```

```
Table 2
id
1
3
4
```

How do I get the ids that are in Table 2 which have the max value in Table 1?

Output:

```
id
1
3
```

I already tried the following to get the max value, but I cannot figure out how to use it in a single query to get the matching rows. Because I think I need to select from the same table I just inner joined.

```
select max(table1.value) 
from table2 
inner join table1 on table1.id = table2.id;
```

Comment: First join the two tables, then get the rows with the maximum value from that result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1 for how to do the second step.

Comment: I already tried `select max(table1.value) from table2 inner join table1 on table1.id = table2.id;` to get the max value, I can't figure out how to reuse it to get rows.

Comment: Show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options available without using window functions:

1. You can use a `WHERE` clause to select only `id` values that have a `value` equal to the `MAX(value)` from your query and an `id` that is in `Table2`:

```
    SELECT t1.id
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE value = (
      SELECT MAX(t1.value)
      FROM Table2 t2
      JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
    )
    AND id IN (SELECT id FROM Table2)
```

2. You can `JOIN` your query to `Table1` and `Table2` again, matching  the `value` in `Table1` and the `id` in `Table2`:

```
    SELECT t1.id
    FROM (
      SELECT MAX(t1.value) AS max_value
      FROM Table2 t2
      JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
    ) t
    JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.value = t.max_value
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

In both cases the output is

```
id
1
3
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afa5c59/4)

Comment: What if adding row (6,3) in Table 1? Your method will return 6 as well but 6 is not in Table 2

Answer (score 4):

Here is one method:

```
select t2.id
from (select t2.*, rank() over (order by value desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2 join
           table1 t1
           on t2.id = t1.id
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or, an alternative that puts all the ids on one row:

```
select group_concat(t2.id) as ids
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.id = t1.id
group by t1.value
order by t1.value desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Too low to comment but from the SQL statement you gave, you just need to add the tableid in your select parameters.

```
select table2.id, max(table1.value) 
from table2 
inner join table1 on table1.id = table2.id;
```